# How to resolve variables in Yaml in Terraform configuration

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I am trying to use this module:

https://github.com/philips-labs/terraform-aws-github-runner/blob/main/modules/multi-runner/runners.tf

This is my yaml

```
matcherConfig:
  exactMatch: true
  labelMatchers:
    - [self-hosted, linux, arm64, amazon]
fifo: true
delay_webhook_event: 0
redrive_build_queue:
  enabled: false
  maxReceiveCount: null
runner_config:
  runner_os: linux
  runner_architecture: arm64
  runner_extra_labels: "ubuntu,amd64,default"
  runner_group_name: default
  runner_name_prefix: amazon-arm64_
  enable_organization_runners: true
  enable_runner_binaries_syncer: false
  enable_ssm_on_runners: true
  block_device_mappings: ${block_device_mappings}
  runner_run_as: "ghrunner"
  create_service_linked_role_spot: true
  runner_metadata_options:
    http_endpoint : enabled
    http_put_response_hop_limit : 1
    http_tokens : required
    instance_metadata_tags : enabled
  enable_jit_config: false
  instance_types:
    - c4.xlarge
```

This is my variable definition

```
variable "block_device_mappings" {
  type = list(object({
    delete_on_termination = optional(bool, true)
    device_name           = optional(string, "/dev/xvda")
    encrypted             = optional(bool, true)
    iops                  = optional(number)
    kms_key_id            = optional(string)
    snapshot_id           = optional(string)
    throughput            = optional(number)
    volume_size           = number
    volume_type           = optional(string, "gp3")
  }))
  default = [{
    volume_size = 30
  }]
}


locals {
  # Load runner configurations from Yaml files
  multi_runner_config = { for c in fileset("${path.module}/templates/runner-configs", "*.yaml") : trimsuffix(c, ".yaml") => yamldecode(file("${path.module}/templates/runner-configs/${c}")) }
    
}
```

How can I pass the variable block device mapping to the yaml template. Any suggestions?

What is the best way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

If I am understanding your question correctly, you need to add the value from your variable to the YAML you read.

This is quite easy to achieve with the `merge` function ([docs](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/functions/merge)). You just need to change your local to:

```
locals {
  # Load runner configurations from Yaml files
  multi_runner_config = { for c in fileset("${path.module}/templates/runner-configs", "*.yaml") : trimsuffix(c, ".yaml") => merge(
    yamldecode(file("${path.module}/templates/runner-configs/${c}")),
    { runner_config = { block_device_mappings = var.block_device_mappings } }
  ) }
}
```

By doing this, you update the value of the YAML's runner_config.block_device_mappings with the value from your variable.

Comment: what will be the value in yaml file?  like this   `block_device_mappings: ${block_device_mappings}`

Comment: The value in the YAML file will not be altered. If you want the While in the Terraform local value `multi_runner_config` the `block_device_mappings` block will be replaced by the value of the variable `var.block_device_mappings`. If you need this new object to be exported back to a YAML file, you may use a `local_file` resource block with `content = yamlencode(local.multi_runner_config)`.

Comment: To be clear, you do not even need to have a `block_device_mappings: ${block_device_mappings}` placeholder in the YAML.

Comment: so i dont need to have any variable included in the yaml. Just add those variables in  multi conifg var in local

Comment: Yes exactly, you may remove `block_device_mappings: ${block_device_mappings}` from your YAML